# When using multivariate regression with a mix of binary and continuous predictors, is it necessary to still run a T Test for the binary predictors?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, t-test, multivariate-analysis

When using multivariate regression with a mix of binary and continuous predictors, is it necessary to still run a T Test for the binary predictors or can that information be found in the regression?

Really, I'm wanting to know this for only one of the categorical variables. I want to know if there exist a significant difference between the means of these two groups (let's say it's gender).

Comment: Please say more; it'll help people help you. E.g., Who says it's necessary...  Under what circumstances would it prove necessary for you..What regression have you conducted for which you need help understanding the results (in that case please display them)...What makes you consider multivariate regression instead of just testing for a gender difference.

Comment: I must run this regression as per instructor, but I need to still see the difference between these means. Is it necessary to do the T-Test or to see difference between means or will the regression suffice.